# How can I bind all the tables in a DataSet to a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagridview

I am trying to bind the tables in a `DataSet` each to their own `DataGrid`, but am not sure how I can go about doing this, here is what I have tried:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding CalibrationData.CalibrationValuestoWrite}">

    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    </DataGrid>

</ListView>
```

Perhaps I need to create a `DataTemplate`? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can only bind the `ItemsSource` property to an `IEnumerable`. What is `CalibrationData.CalibrationValuestoWrite`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only bind the `ItemsSource` property to an `IEnumerable`. And you define an `ItemTemplate` to define the appearance of each item that the enumerable returns.

So if `CalibrationData.CalibrationValuestoWrite` returns an `IEnumerable<DataTable>` (the `DataSet.Tables` property does) and you want to display a `DataGrid` for each `DataTable`, this should work:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding CalibrationData.CalibrationValuestoWrite.Tables}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: I've used this approach and I find it a very flexible way to leverage a `ListView` but still get that "real grid" feel from it.

Comment: Oh okay, do you know how I could cast a `DataSet` as an `IEnumerable<DataTable>`?

Comment: @Alfie: Bind to the `Tables` property of the `DataSet`.

Comment: I've just tried this, using the example you've given above but sadly it doesn't seem to work

Comment: @Alfie: It should work provided that the binding to the DataSet property actually works. Make sure that you have set the DataContext properly.

Answer (score 5):

**Try this hope it's helps you**

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="250" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,40,0,0" Name="mytbl" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="479">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Col1" Width="50" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Col2" Width="375"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Col3" Width="50"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

**Code behind**

```
this.mytbl.DataContext = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

Comment: FYI:  you don't need to tag OP in anything on their own question, as they will automatically receive notification of any comments, answers, etc. that get posted.

Answer (score 0):

Better to bind with a DataView like in this small example here:

(vm is the datacontext of XAML view).

XAML:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyGrid}">
</DataGrid>
```

C#, ViewModel

```
    public partial class vm : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
      protected void OnPropertyChanged(string text)
      {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(text));
        }
      } 

      public vm()
      {
        DataTable dt;

        ...

        MyGrid = new DataView(dt);
      }

      private DataView _mygrid;
      public DataView MyGrid
      {
         get
         {
            return _mygrid;
         }
         set
         {
            _mygrid= value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MyGrid");
         }
      }
   }
```